# With Apache is it possible to do a RewriteCond on a derivative of a server variable?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do the following rewrite:

If the filename is `/files/styles/*/*/*.*` and the file `/files/*.*` does not exist, then rewrite to another domain.

To do this with PERL regex would be something like the following:

```
s/\/files(\/styles\/[^\/]+?/[^\/]+?)(\/.*)$/\/files$2/
```

Is it possible to do this with Apache mod_rewrite.  Something along the lines of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^files/styles.*$
RewriteCond [derivative of %{REQUEST_FILENAME}] !-f 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `%1` to get backreferences of a previous RewriteCond. You can try something like this:

```
# Is the request */files/styles/*/*/*.* 
# Set a backreference which will be the docroot (*)/files....
# Set a backreference which will be the filename (*.*).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/files/styles/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$
# Check to see if backreference exists.
RewriteCond %1/files/%2 !-f
# Redirect.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```